# Printing unique lines with uniq, OS X Yosemite

Tags: unix, terminal, osx-yosemite, uniq

I am trying to print the unique entries in a column of a `.csv` file. For this, I tried the following:

```
awk -F "," '{print $6}' dataCoarse.csv | uniq -u
```

which just prints the 6th column as it is. There are still duplicate entries. How can I print only the unique lines?

Edit: I think I need to remove the blank spaces preceding or trailing any character on each line, or have `uniq` somehow disregard them. How can I do this?

Comment: have you try w/o -u?

Comment: Yes, I think it makes no difference. I think some lines have an extra space char at the end, making the comparison invalid.

Comment: So strip this character, something like (before uniq) can do the work: sed 's/ $//'. Or strip it within awk

Comment: I have stripped all the blanks using `sed 's/ //'` but it still sees two identical entries as unique, and prints out separately.

Comment: try to dump them with od -ax command to check the hex values

Comment: They look identical as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too! [Check out this solution to a similar problem.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536775/uniq-command-not-working-properly/536783) Basically, you want to pipe your data to `sort` first, as `uniq` only counts consecutive instances of your data as duplicate.

`awk -F "," '{print $6}' dataCoarse.csv | sort -u` should give you the output you're looking for.

Comment: even better sort -u will sort and give uniq result.

Comment: You're right! Forgot about that one. Edited per your suggestion.